# Draw small symmetrical arc line path between two markers on world map in Highmaps

Tags: javascript, math, svg, highcharts

I'm using Highmaps to create a flight path chart, using their demo [Simple flight routes](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/flight-routes) ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/flight-routes/)) as a starting point. When I update the code to use a world map the line paths between locations/markers become distorted with an exaggerated curve.

See [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chickensoup64/qLuv6bra/) where I have only modified from the demo to the following:

**HTML**

```html
<!-- line 5 -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
// line 39
mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
// line 47
data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world'], 'mapline'),
```

See the difference between both where *before* is the Highcharts demo and *after* is my few changes as noted above:

[image: comparison of map line paths]

The paths are calculated through function `pointsToPath` which uses quadratic Bézier curve `Q` in SVG to curve the line drawn between markers.

```js
// Function to return an SVG path between two points, with an arc
function pointsToPath(from, to, invertArc) {
    var arcPointX = (from.x + to.x) / (invertArc ? 2.4 : 1.6),
        arcPointY = (from.y + to.y) / (invertArc ? 2.4 : 1.6);
    return 'M' + from.x + ',' + from.y + 'Q' + arcPointX + ' ' + arcPointY +
            ',' + to.x + ' ' + to.y;
}
```

If I modify the function to always divide by `2` for arc points `x` and `y` then I get a straight line between markers:

```js
var arcPointX = (from.x + to.x) / 2,
    arcPointY = (from.y + to.y) / 2;
```

I'm not sure of the math to get a smaller, less exaggerated curve.

Ideally I would like for the line to be symmetrical as per an example from [MDN - Paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves):

[image: Quadratic Bézier with grid]

```html
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 10 80 Q 95 10 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

Using world map data, how do I calculate line paths between markers to appear with a smaller or symmetrical curve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to get your denominator closer to 2.0 as when it is 2.0 is a perfectly straight line: https://jsfiddle.net/my7bx50p/1/

So I chose 2.03 and 1.97 and that gives you much "softer" curves. Hope that helps.

```
function pointsToPath(from, to, invertArc) {
    var arcPointX = (from.x + to.x) / (invertArc ? 2.03 : 1.97),
        arcPointY = (from.y + to.y) / (invertArc ? 2.03 : 1.97);
    return 'M' + from.x + ' ' + from.y + 'Q' + arcPointX + ' ' + arcPointY + ' ' + to.x + ' ' + to.y;
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I tried to focus in only on the math: https://jsfiddle.net/9gkvhfuL/1/

I think the math is now correct:

[image]

Which back to the real example: https://jsfiddle.net/my7bx50p/6/

Gives, I believe, the desired outcome :):

[image]

From the code (https://jsfiddle.net/my7bx50p/6/):

```
  function pointsToPath(from, to, invertArc) {
var centerPoint = [ (from.x + to.x) / 2, (from.y + to.y) / 2];
var slope = (to.x - from.x) / (to.y - from.y);
var invSlope = -1 / slope;
var distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((to.x - from.x), 2) + Math.pow((to.y - from.y), 2) );

if (Math.abs(slope) > Math.abs(invSlope) ){
  //then we should offset in the y direction
  var offset = (invertArc ? -1 : 1) * 2 * Math.sqrt(distance);
  var min_slope = Math.min( Math.abs(slope), Math.abs(invSlope) );
  var final_slope = Math.max(min_slope, 1);
  var offsetCenter = [centerPoint[0] + (offset * (1/slope)), centerPoint[1] + offset];
  //console.log(centerPoint, slope, invSlope, distance);
  var arcPointX = offsetCenter[0], //(from.x + to.x) / (invertArc ? 2.03 : 1.97),
      arcPointY = offsetCenter[1] //(from.y + to.y) / (invertArc ? 2.03 : 1.97);
} else{ //invSlope <= slope
  //then we should offset in the x direction
  var offset = (invertArc ? -1 : 1) * 2 * Math.sqrt(distance);
  var min_slope = Math.min( Math.abs(slope), Math.abs(invSlope) );
  var final_slope = Math.max(min_slope, 1);
  var offsetCenter = [centerPoint[0] + offset, centerPoint[1] + (offset * (1/invSlope))];
  //console.log(centerPoint, slope, invSlope, distance);
  var arcPointX = offsetCenter[0], //(from.x + to.x) / (invertArc ? 2.03 : 1.97),
      arcPointY = offsetCenter[1] //(from.y + to.y) / (invertArc ? 2.03 : 1.97);
}   
return 'M' + from.x + ' ' + from.y + 'Q' + arcPointX + ' ' + arcPointY +
        ' ' + to.x + ' ' + to.y;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** (to try to explain the math and clean up the code)

Check out the Math Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/dcormfxy/53/

[image]

The solid black line between the two points is the straight line between them and it also has the corresponding slope (used in the code later). I also drew a centre point on each line. Then I drew the inverse slope as a dotted line (also used in the code) The inverse slope is by definition perpendicular to the slope and is related by `invSlope = -1/slope`. From this, we are now set up to find the perpendicular points to the left or right of the centre point, that will become the centre of our symmetrical arcs. We do this by first figuring out if the slope is greater than the inverse slope or if the inverse slope is greater than the slope (absolute values). This is only necessary because when we have a perfectly horizontal or perfectly vertical line then the slope is zero and undefined respectively and then our math doesn't work. (remember slope = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) so when the line is vertical y-changes but x-doesn't so x2 = x1 and then the denominator is zero and gives us undefined slope)

Let's think about line C `from : {x: 40, y: 40}, to : {x: 220, y: 40}`

slope = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)

slope = (40 - 40)/(220 - 40)

slope = 0 / 180

slope = 0

invSlope = -1/slope

invSlope = undefined

This is why we need to have the two cases (the if else) in the code as whenever we get slope or invSlope as undefined the math is not going to work. So now, although slope is zero, it is greater than invSlope (undefined). (note SVGs are upside down compared to normal charts and how we think about them so it requires your brain to keep that in mind, otherwise, it's easy to get lost)

So now we can offset the centre point in the y-direction and then figure out how much we have to offset in the x-direction. If you had a line with slope 1, then you would offset the same in the x and the y-directions because the slope of the line is 1 (line makes a 45-degree angle with the x-axis) and so moving perpendicularly away from that line is achieved just by moving for example 5 in the x-direction and -5 in the y-direction.

Luckily, with this edge case (slope = 0), then we just move in the y-direction and the x-direction offset = 0. Look at line C in the math example and you can see what I mean, to move perpendicularly, we just move either positive or negative y-direction from the centre point. From the code:

`offsetCenter = [centerPoint[0] + (offset * (1/slope)), centerPoint[1] + offset];`

So as I said, we offset in the y-direction from the centerPoint and the term `+ (offset * (1/slope))` will be zero here because 1/slope is undefined. We can chose to offset "left" or "right" by the function's argument `invertArc` which is used in this line: `var offset = (invertArc ? -1 : 1) * 2 * Math.sqrt(distance);` which basically means move postive or negative direction away from the centerPoint in a magnitude equal to two times the square root of the distance between the points. I settled on two times the square root of the distance between the points because this gives us an offsetCenter of our arc that gives similarly soft curves for all lines both short and long.

Now, let's think about line A `from : {x: 40, y: 40}, to : {x: 320, y: 360}`

slope = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)

slope = (360 - 40)/(320 - 40)

slope = 320 / 280

slope = 1.143

invSlope = -1/slope

invSlope = -0.875

Final cleaned up code and real example here https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/o43ka9u5/4/:

```
  function pointsToPath(from, to, invertArc) {
  var centerPoint = [ (from.x + to.x) / 2, (from.y + to.y) / 2];
  var slope = (to.x - from.x) / (to.y - from.y);
  var invSlope = -1 / slope;
  var distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((to.x - from.x), 2) + Math.pow((to.y - from.y), 2) );
  var arcPointX = 0;
  var arcPointY = 0;
  var offset = 0;
  var offsetCenter = 0;

  if (Math.abs(slope) > Math.abs(invSlope) ){
    //then we should offset in the y direction (then calc. x-offset)
    offset = (invertArc ? -1 : 1) * 2 * Math.sqrt(distance);

    offsetCenter = [centerPoint[0] + (offset * (1/slope)), centerPoint[1] + offset];

    arcPointX = offsetCenter[0] 
    arcPointY = offsetCenter[1]
  } else{ //invSlope >= slope
    //then we should offset in the x direction (then calc. y-offset)
    offset = (invertArc ? -1 : 1) * 2 * Math.sqrt(distance);
    offsetCenter = [centerPoint[0] + offset, centerPoint[1] + (offset * (1/invSlope))];

    arcPointX = offsetCenter[0] 
    arcPointY = offsetCenter[1] 
  }   
  return 'M' + from.x + ' ' + from.y + 'Q' + arcPointX + ' ' + arcPointY +
          ' ' + to.x + ' ' + to.y;
  }
```

**UPDATE 3:**

I figured out how to remove the need for the if else control flow / switch statement by using trigonometry instead. I hope my sketch helps explain the logic, you might also want to read some stuff (https://study.com/academy/lesson/sohcahtoa-definition-example-problems-quiz.html) etc. as I would struggle to explain briefly here (and I am already writing an essay here :) so will not explain SOH CAH TOA etc.)

[image]

This makes the core function code like this (Math only - https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/dcormfxy/107/) (full example - https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/o43ka9u5/6/):

```
function pointsToPath(from, to, invertArc) {
  const centerPoint = [ (from.x + to.x) / 2, (from.y + to.y) / 2];
  const slope = (to.y - from.y) / (to.x - from.x);
  const invSlope = -1 / slope;
  const distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((to.x - from.x), 2) + Math.pow((to.y - from.y), 2) );
  const offset = (invertArc ? -1 : 1) * 2 * Math.sqrt(distance);

  const angle = Math.atan(slope);
  //Math.cos(angle) = offsetY/offset;
  //Math.sin(angle) = offsetX/offset;
  const offsetY = Math.cos(angle)*offset;
  const offsetX = Math.sin(angle)*offset;
  //if slope = 0 then effectively only offset y-direction
  const offsetCenter = [centerPoint[0] - offsetX, centerPoint[1] + offsetY];
  const arcPointX = offsetCenter[0]
  const arcPointY = offsetCenter[1]   
  return 'M' + from.x + ' ' + from.y + 'Q' + arcPointX + ' ' + arcPointY +
          ' ' + to.x + ' ' + to.y;
 }
```

I believe this code is more elegant, cleaner and more robust and mathematically valid :) Thanks also Ash for the tips on Const & Let use versus var.

This also gives the final result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did try that but the reason I didn't stick with it was because none of the lines are consistent. For example the *London - Bristol* line has a much higher curve than *Belfast - Lerwick* which is almost straight. I don't think magic numbers would be the answer, perhaps I'm wrong here?

Comment: Ahh ok now I understand what you want to do. So I should calculate the midpoint of the line (between the two airports) and then make the arc point (point of the curve) slightly away from this, such that each line has a similarly nice "soft" curve. Let me try and figure out the math.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it; I described it as symmetrical. A consistent soft curve for each line between two points (i.e. flight path between airports). Remember this will need to scale up to a global map as per my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/chickensoup64/qLuv6bra/ - I'm stuck on the math too so I'm keen to see what you come up with. Thanks for your time and thought.

Comment: I made an updated attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/my7bx50p/4/ - seems to be much closer to the ideal outcome?

Comment: Now I finally have it :) Math only - https://jsfiddle.net/9gkvhfuL/1/ Or real example - https://jsfiddle.net/my7bx50p/6/

Comment: That's exactly what I need and it's working well. There are some scoping issues with a couple of variables, `arcPointX` and `arcPointY` for example. If you can clean that up then I'll accept the answer (I'm happy to edit if you'd like my input in your answer). As a bonus, if you could explain a little bit more about some of the maths or link to resources I'd be keen to learn and understand.

Comment: Awesome, I am working on trying to explain all the math/logic in my answer now. I did not use any resources, I just sketched it out on paper and tried to work through the math myself (I studied science & math in my degree). I am not a computer scientist so my code can always do with improving, any tips would be highly appreciated. I tried to clean it up here: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/o43ka9u5/4/: and here: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/dcormfxy/53/.

Comment: The explanations were awesome! Your code improvements are pretty good now, the only change I would suggest is to use `const` and `let` instead of `var`, but it's not essential. Use `const` for values which won't change and `let` if you need to update the value. E.g. `const invSlope = -1 / slope;` and `let arcPointX = 0;`. Awesome work!

Comment: Thanks Ash, I also now figured out how to remove the if/else control flow/switch statement by using trigonometry, I think this is cleaner, simpler and more mathematically valid :) - Thanks for the tips on Const & Let :)