# how create a circle group a organization circle image and connect with curve line with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to create a radial (circular) grouped circle with d3.js, something like:

[image]

i write some code like below.

but i do not know how conect every circle with curve line, and when mouse hover circle, the circle above will show a tooltip, how to do that? Help will be appreciated.Thanks.

i update my code,now i can draw circle or a image element in a big circle.

```js
    const mockedData = {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "name": "Node1one",
        "label": "Node1",
        "id": 1,
        "x": 120,
        "y": 120,
      },
      {
        "name": "Node2",
        "label": "Node2",
        "id": 2,
        "x": 350,
        "y": 180,
      },
    ]
  }

  const imgList = {
    "images": [
      {
        "image": 'https://via.placeholder.com/30x30',
        "x": -50,
      },
      {
        "image": 'https://via.placeholder.com/30',
        "x": 20
      }
    ]
  }


const svg = d3.select("svg");
const width = +svg.attr("width");
const height = +svg.attr("height");

let { links, nodes } = mockedData;

let { images } = imgList;

const ticked = ( node) => {
  node.attr("transform", 
  function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";});
}

const tickedImg = (nodeImg) => {
  nodeImg.attr("x", function (d) {return  d.x })
}

const node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")

    node.append('circle').attr("r", 86); //radius
    svg.selectAll('circle')
    .on('click', function () { // arrow function will produce this = undefined
       d3.selectAll('circle')
       .style("fill", "lightgray");
       d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "aliceblue");
     })
     .on('mouseover', function () {
        d3.selectAll('circle')
        .style("stroke", "black");
        
        d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke", "green");
    })
    ticked( node )




const nodeText = node.append("text")
.attr("y", -70);

      nodeText.selectAll("tspan.text")
      .data((d) =>  d.name.split(" "))
      .enter()
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("class", "text")
      .text(d => d)
      .attr("x", -30)
      .attr("y", -60)

      node.append("title")
          .text(function (d) {return d.id;});

const nodeImg = node.selectAll("image")
        .data(images)
        .enter()
        .append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", (d) => d.image)
        .attr("width", 27)
        .attr("height", 30)
        tickedImg (nodeImg)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 2000 1000"></svg>
```

Comment: @Alex L thank you eidt the code

Comment: No worries, try to always set-up a minimal reproducible example when you can - code snippets help this. If I get time later, I will post an answer. Quick question, in ``mockedData.nodes`` what links should be used for each node? You have ``links: [1,2]`` and ``links: [2,3]`` but your  ``mockedData.links`` only has two links? And the second link has a target of 3, but where is 3?

Comment: @Alex L thanks, yes, the links should be used each node .My original idea was that there are 3 small circles in the large circle, and the number of links determines the number of connecting lines between the small circles.My English is not very good, I wonder if my statement is clear?

Comment: looking forward to your reply

Comment: Sorry @Janily I didn't understand exactly how ``links: [1,2]`` and ``links: [2,3]`` and ``mockedData.links`` are all connected to the image you shared? Can you explain again? You can also comment here in your native language if you like and I will use Google Translate if I don't understand it (I speak English, German and a bit of Spanish)?

Comment: I'm confused because your data has 2 nodes, each with 2 links? But your image is 2 big circles with 3 circles inside all connected. I can't see how your data makes that output?

Comment: @Alex L i update my code,you can run the code.now there are two picture in the big circle,now i want to connect the two picture with curved line.i remove the links,I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if we just want to draw curved arcs between the images I can certainly help :)

I answered (in quite a lot of detail) a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784798/9792594 - this should help explain the math etc.

I will just use the final function from that answer, and if you need background on how it works, check out that answer.

Note: you can change the "z-order" of the svg elements just by changing the "paint order", i.e. the order in which you render them in the DOM. So in d3, using `.append()`, this just means calling the code you want on the bottom layer first, and then calling the code you want above that next, and so on.

```js
const mockedData = {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "name": "Node1",
        "label": "Node1",
        "id": 1,
        "x": 120,
        "y": 120,
      },
      {
        "name": "Node2",
        "label": "Node2",
        "id": 2,
        "x": 350,
        "y": 180,
      },
    ]
  }

  const imgList = {
    "images": [
      {
        "image": 'https://via.placeholder.com/30x30',
        "width": 30,
        "height": 30,
        "x": -50,
        "y": -20
      },
      {
        "image": 'https://via.placeholder.com/30',
        "width": 30,
        "height": 30,
        "x": 20,
        "y": -20
      },
      {
        "image": 'https://via.placeholder.com/30',
        "width": 30,
        "height": 30,
        "x": -15,
        "y": 20
      }
    ]
  }


const svg = d3.select("svg");
const width = +svg.attr("width");
const height = +svg.attr("height");

let { links, nodes } = mockedData;

let { images } = imgList;

const ticked = ( node) => {
  node.attr("transform", 
  function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";});
}

const tickedImg = (nodeImg) => {
  nodeImg.attr("x", function (d) {return  d.x })
}

const node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes);
        
    node
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", (d,i) => {
          //console.log(d,i,images)
          if (nodes.length > 1){
            const j = i == (nodes.length - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;
            const invertArc = (i+1) < (nodes.length/2);
            const gtr2 = nodes.length > 2 ? invertArc : !invertArc;
            //console.log(i,invertArc)
            return pointsToPath(d, nodes[j], gtr2);
          }
          return "";
        })
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", "4")
        .attr("fill", "transparent");
        
const nodeGroup = node        
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node");
        
const circle = nodeGroup.append('circle').attr("r", 86); //radius
circle
    .style("fill", "darkgray")
    .on('click', function () { // arrow function will produce this = undefined
       d3.selectAll('circle')
       .style("fill", "darkgray");
       d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "aliceblue");
     })
     .on('mouseover', function () {
        d3.selectAll('circle')
        .style("stroke", "black");

        d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke", "green");
    })
    ticked( nodeGroup );

const nodeText = nodeGroup.append("text")
      .attr("y", -70);

nodeText.selectAll("tspan.text")
      .data((d) =>  d.name.split(" "))
      .enter()
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("class", "text")
      .text(d => d)
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("x", -30)
      .attr("y", -60)

nodeGroup.append("title")
      .text(function (d) {return d.id;});

const nodeImg = nodeGroup.selectAll("image")
      .data(images);
nodeImg      
      .enter()
      .append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", d => d.image)
      .attr("width", d => d.width)
      .attr("height", d => d.height)
      .attr("x", d => d.x)
      .attr("y", d => d.y)
      //tickedImg (nodeImg)
      
      
nodeImg      
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", (d,i) => {
        //console.log(d,i,images)
        if (images.length > 1){
          const j = i == (images.length - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;
          const invertArc = (i+1) < (images.length/2);
          //console.log(i,invertArc)
          return pointsToPath(d, images[j], invertArc);
        }
        return "";
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", "4")
      .attr("fill", "transparent")
      .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.width/2 + ", " + d.height/2 + ")");
      //tickedImg (nodeImg)      
   
      
function pointsToPath(from, to, invertArc) {
  const centerPoint = [ (from.x + to.x) / 2, (from.y + to.y) / 2];
  const slope = (to.y - from.y) / (to.x - from.x);
  const invSlope = -1 / slope;
  const distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((to.x - from.x), 2) + Math.pow((to.y - from.y), 2) );
  const offset = (invertArc ? -1 : 1) * 2 * Math.sqrt(distance);

  const angle = Math.atan(slope);
  const offsetY = Math.cos(angle)*offset;
  const offsetX = Math.sin(angle)*offset;
  const offsetCenter = [centerPoint[0] - offsetX, centerPoint[1] + offsetY];
  const arcPointX = offsetCenter[0]
  const arcPointY = offsetCenter[1]   
  return 'M' + from.x + ' ' + from.y + 'Q' + arcPointX + ' ' + arcPointY +
          ' ' + to.x + ' ' + to.y;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 1000 500">
  <path d="M20 20 50 50" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" stroke="black"></path>
</svg>

<script>
//the following d3 code would insert the same path as that manually inserted in the HTML above:
d3.select("svg")
  .append("path")
  //we can set it directly as below, or via a function:
  .attr("d", "M20 20 50 50")
  .attr("fill", "transparent")
  .attr("stroke-width", "5")
  .attr("stroke", "black");
</script>
```

Output (updated 18-Jun-20):

[image]

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it. Does the code make sense? If you have a question about it, just let me know. If my answer solved your problem, please consider to mark it as accepted :) Thanks

Comment: hi Alex,if i want to set path element to position individually,how to do that?

Comment: A Path has a "d" attribute, in order to describe its path. It can become quite complicated as you begin to describe more complex paths. But in general, you can for example draw a line from ``x: 20, y:20`` to ``x:50, y:50`` with this d path: "M20 20 50 50" I added this path manually to your HTML now. Does that make sense? - more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves

Comment: thanks Alex, i means how to control individually path with transform,below picture: https://tva1.sinaimg.cn/large/007S8ZIlgy1gfvjzk9fghj31nb0u041q.jpg

Comment: i can set the transform with parmars in imgList object. for example,add a parameter to the second attribute in the imgList object to control the position of the path.Is there any other way?

Comment: Ahh ok, you mean, I used the width and height of each image object that I added to your ``imgList`` array? this line ``.attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.width/2 + ", " + d.height/2 + ")");`` and you want to know can you set the transform another way? Yeah you could use a global constant somewhere in your code like ``const imgWidth = 30`` and then change that line to ``.attr("transform", d => "translate(" + imgWidth /2 + ", " + imgWidth /2 + ")");`` or you could hard code a number like 30 etc.? Up to you. D3 = "Data Driven Documents", so I always start with the data

Comment: Alex,Thank you for your patience.

Comment: if i want whether it is two or three pictures, it can be automatically connected by a curve, and the two large circles are also connected by a curve. Is there any good way to do this? The effect shown in the figure below.https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hwd2.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216190/discussion-between-janily-and-alex-l).